# Suggestion for a Magento Startup MultiStore Project

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shipping, custom-options, product-list

This is my first Magento project, and I am trying my level best to learn as early as possible, but still some doubts arise for which I need some guidance from Magento Experts.

In this project I am going to sell Grocery items, but some items are not available at some cities, so I plan to start the web site asking the customer their zip code and accordingly available products will display for that zip code area.

Initially I am starting with 1 city but within 1 month I will expand this for major 5 cities and gradually increase by states.

I welcome any suggestions for -

1. How can I get the a pop like shown in attached image when website open, initially I will take only 1 state, 1 city and multiple zip code for that city.

[image: POP UP WHEN WEB SITE OPEN]

2. Depending on the city only available products should display.
   Example- X product is available for City_1, City_4 and city_9 only, so only X   should come on product page for these 3 cities or for other cities it should display "Not Available".
3. Depending on the distance how to set shipping charge.

It will be very appreciable if you experts hold my finger show me the right way to move.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a complicated problem and would require some decent Magento knowledge to build custom extension(s) to be able to manage those locations and show/hide products/categories.

**Because this is your first Magento project i would probably recommend an extension to solve your problem, and probably tweak it a bit if needed to suit your needs.**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zones-manager.html

> Zones Manager Magento extension enables to create and manage geo zones with their own settings. It assigns the customer to a certain zone depending on his / here place of residence. For each zone the next options can be defined: minimum order amount, product prices, catalog price rules, allowed stores, currencies, payment methods, shipping methods, catalog categories and products.

Also take a look at

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/geoip-ultimate-lock-website-security.html

> GEO-IP Ultimate Lock Make your website secure from unwanted visitors of certain location or limit the access of certain products or categories with Magento GEOIP Ultimate Lock extension by FME. Using this module, you can quickly block certain IP addresses with great ease. The extension uses the functionality of catalog price rules for which you select attributes like SKU, color, and price. Using these attributes, it blocks access to the selected categories or products.

In case that the Regions that you want to manage and have different products are not too many. 
You could probably create different store views for each city/region and then programmatically set the correct region based on a user selection.
    For example you can have a pop up when the user loads the page for first time , allow them to select the city/region, set it to Magento and save it for that user.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870417/magento-set-store-id-programatically